# strsplit does not split for all elements of character vector provided to parameter "split"

Tags: r

The R documentation for the `strsplit` function states for parameter `split` that *"If split has length greater than 1, it is re-cycled along x."*

I take it to mean that if I use the following code

```
strsplit(x = "Whatever will be will be", split = c("ever", "be"))
```

..., I will get `x` split into "What" and "will" and "will be". This does not happen. The output is "What" and "will be will be".

Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Also, how can I get the result I desire?

Answer (score 2):

The arguments in split will be recycled if also `x` has multiple arguments:

```
strsplit(x = c("Whatever will be will be","Whatever will be will be"), 
         split = c("ever", "be"))
[[1]]
[1] "What"             " will be will be"

[[2]]
[1] "Whatever will " " will "
```

The behaviour I suspect you expect is achieved with a `|`:

```
strsplit(x = "Whatever will be will be", split = c("ever|be"))
[[1]]
[1] "What"   " will " " will "
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split` is recycled across *elements* of x, so that the first element of split is applied to the first element of x, the second to the second, etc. So, for example:

```
strsplit(x = c("Whatever will be will be", "Whatever will be will be"), split = c("ever", "be"))
[[1]]
[1] "What"             " will be will be"

[[2]]
[1] "Whatever will " " will "
```

Comment: Heh, three identical answers with the exact same example in the span of 11 seconds. :)