# Split data on specific words

Tags: r, string, split

I have vector of Universities and their country name joined together (happened while copying data from the site). I want to seperate out universities name from country and put them in different columns - university and country. The vector is long. I have just put sample of values. 
I tried to create a vector for split ie Country names. it did not work.

```
word <- c('JNUIndia','IITIndia','OxfordUnited Kingdom')
strsplit(word, split=c('India'))  #this worked
strsplit(word, split=c('United Kingdom')) # this also worked
strsplit(word, split=c('India','United Kingdom')) #this did not work
```

Comment: Try using the pipe character in in the split argument instead: `strsplit(word, split=c('India|United Kingdom'))`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158774/8562539

Comment: How do extract country names in 2nd column. I would need a DF with University and Countries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative. Of course it will get time consuming for many countries but it does get you the countries.

```
strsplit(word,"\\JNU|IIT|Oxford")
```